# Having problems with Stack trace errors

Tags: android

i'm new to android studio and my app is crushing besuase line of code

```
songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

posting a question here helped me to realize it is a typo with an id in my layout. Well, here is the code for my layout with songProgressBar as an id.

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="25dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_above="@id/player_footer_bg"
android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_blue"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:paddingRight="6dp"/>
```

Now, i don't know what the typo is, and i don't know what i'm to do. the person who told me it is a typo said i should check whether the component is present in the layout when the activity is running. I've got no idea what I'm to do now. pls help.

Comment: Add your activity here so you'll probably get more in-depth answers.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a null pointer exception.

21:39:10.999 1443-1443/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 01-10 21:39:10.999 1443-1443/? E/AndroidRuntime: at com.example.passion.patrimusic.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86) 01-10 21:39:10.999

And from your above comment, its possible that songProgressBar is null.
If you are getting it from the layout, check if there's any typo in the Id and whether the component is present in the layout when the activity is running.

Comment: it was a typo err with the seekbar id in layout. but how do I check to know if the seekbar component is in the layout when the activity is running. I'm new to programming. I've used the seekbar_progress drawable, whose id is songProgressBar in my layout design. don't understand how it will not be present when the activity is running.

Comment: You could do a null check on the object after find view by Id.
Are you still getting the null pointer exception after the typo corrected?
 If so, please share the code.