# Can't figure out the errors in my stack trace

Tags: android

I'm new to android studio and my app is crashing because of this line of code

```
  songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
```

Posting a question here helped me to realize it is a typo with an id in my layout. Well, here is the code for my layout with songProgressBar as an id.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/songProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/player_footer_bg"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress_blue"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp"/>
```

Now, I don't know what the typo is, and I don't know what I'm supposed to do. The person who told me it is a typo said i should check whether the component is present in the layout when the activity is running. I've got no idea what I'm to do now.

here is my MainAcivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private ImageButton btnPlay;
private ImageButton btnForward;
private ImageButton btnBackward;
private ImageButton btnNext;
private ImageButton btnPrevious;
private ImageButton btnPlaylist;
private ImageButton btnRepeat;
private ImageButton btnShuffle;
private SeekBar songProgressBar;
private TextView songTitleLabel;
private TextView songCurrentDurationLabel;
private TextView songTotalDurationLabel;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private SongsManager songManager;
private Utilities utils;
private int seekForwardTime = 5000; 
private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; 
private int currentSongIndex = 0;
private boolean isShuffle = false;
private boolean isRepeat = false;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    btnForward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnForward);
    btnBackward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnBackward);
    btnNext = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    btnPrevious = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    btnPlaylist = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPlaylist);
    btnRepeat = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRepeat);
    btnShuffle = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnShuffle);
    songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songCurrentDurationLabel);
    songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songTotalDurationLabel);




    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    songManager = new SongsManager();
    utils = new Utilities();

    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

    playSong(0);

    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(mp.isPlaying()){
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.pause();
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_play);
                }
            }else{
                if(mp!=null){
                    mp.start();
                    btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    btnForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
        }
    });

    btnBackward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
            }else{
                mp.seekTo(0);
            }

        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
                playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
            }else{
                playSong(0);
                currentSongIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    });

    btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(currentSongIndex > 0){
                playSong(currentSongIndex - 1);
                currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex - 1;
            }else{
                playSong(songsList.size() - 1);
                currentSongIndex = songsList.size() - 1;
            }

        }
    });

    btnRepeat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isRepeat){
                isRepeat = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }else{
                isRepeat = true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isShuffle = false;
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat_focused);
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }
        }
    });

    btnShuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(isShuffle){
                isShuffle = false;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle);
            }else{
                isShuffle= true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Shuffle is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isRepeat = false;
                btnShuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_shuffle_focused);
                btnRepeat.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_repeat);
            }
        }
    });

    btnPlaylist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayListActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == 100){
        currentSongIndex = data.getExtras().getInt("songIndex");
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    }

}

public void  playSong(int songIndex){
    try {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");
        songTitleLabel.setText(songTitle);

        btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_pause);

        songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
        songProgressBar.setMax(100);

        updateProgressBar();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void updateProgressBar() {
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
        long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

        songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
        songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

        int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
        songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
        mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
};
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

}
@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
    int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
    mp.seekTo(currentPosition);
    updateProgressBar();
}
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    if(isRepeat){
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else if(isShuffle){
        Random rand = new Random();
        currentSongIndex = rand.nextInt((songsList.size() - 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;
        playSong(currentSongIndex);
    } else{
        if(currentSongIndex < (songsList.size() - 1)){
            playSong(currentSongIndex + 1);
            currentSongIndex = currentSongIndex + 1;
        }else{
            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your previous question if this relates to that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stack trace errors appear not to be from my project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704137/stack-trace-errors-appear-not-to-be-from-my-project)

Comment: Please add more of your code, your XML layout, and the Stack Trace of the crash you are getting to your question, so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704137/stack-trace-errors-appear-not-to-be-from-my-project) was your previous question, which was for a `NullPointerException`. In future, you need to show the stack trace when you ask a question about an exception.

Make sure your `onCreate()` calls `sectContentView()` with the layout that contains the `SeekBar`, and that you call `findViewById` with the correct `ID` for the `SeekBar`. Something like this skeleton:

```
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  // This must be the layout that contains the SeekBar.

    SeekBar songProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
    songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Hello Cybersam, I did do as you suggested, but I'm still getting errors in my stack trace. Here's what I did. I placed this line of code under my onCreate method SeekBar songProgressBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.songProgressBar);
        songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); By the way, the onCreate method does indeed calls the setContentView(). What to do?

Comment: Are you passing the correct layout ID to `setContentView()`? That is, is it the ID for the layout that contains `songProgressBar`?

Comment: Cybersam, I've posted the early part of my main activity, that is my some parts of my MainActivity and oncreate method. Pls do take the bother to look at it and tell me what I'm not doing right. Tried to post my entire MainActivity here but kept getting errors.

Comment: Try NameofYourClass.this instead of simply this in the line of your error. It is expecting a Context object, if I am not mistaken, and sometimes typing simply this is not correct.

Comment: Nah, forget it, I read fast and badly, it is not  expecting a Context, it is expecting the interface you are implementing. Sorry.

Comment: @ Fustigador. So what's wrong with my program now?
What should I do?